# How to customize language view of list in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have installed language pack to SharePoint 2010.

I have created project SharePoint 2010 in Visual Studio. In project, I've created a feature and added resource files RESX and feature receiver method:

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
```

When I create list RESX files translations are not applied when change language. This is my code sample but it is not working:

```
               var listView = new StringCollection();

               listView.Add("$Resources:lblAccountName");  // error

               listView.Add("$Resources:lblFullName");  // error

               list.Views.Add("view1", listView, string.Empty, 30, true, true);

               list.Update();
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: What the exact error is? Can you provide a message and stack trace if possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would always create a ResourceManager object to retrieve strings from a localized resource file. E.g.

```
public static ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("MyProject.SharePointRoot.Resources.LanguageLocalization", typeof(MyProject.SharePointRoot.Resources.LanguageLocalization).Assembly);
```

Note: "LanguageLocalization" was the name of my resources resx file.

And then:

```
          var listView = new StringCollection();

           listView.Add(rm.GetString("lblAccountName"));

           listView.Add(rm.GetString("lblFullName"));

           list.Views.Add("view1", listView, string.Empty, 30, true, true);

           list.Update();
```

See here for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx